# how to know what ran from upsert query

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-2016

I have a query

```
<cfquery name="qryTemp" datasource="someDSN">
if not exists (select someID from tempTable where someID = 20)
insert into tempTable (someID, colA, colB) values (1,2,3)
else
update tempTable set
colA = 2, colB =3
where someID = 1
</query>
```

Is there any identifier which can point out whether it was an insert or update? I can add result attribute to the query if that can help.

Comment: Instead of cramming up all the operations in the same `<cfquery>` block, you can split them up in to individual queries.

Comment: What version of SQL?

Comment: @RRK Using an `UPSERT` methodology is very valid SQL, and it skips the application check and potential extra query to determine whether you want to try an `INSERT` or an `UPDATE`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would try giving the `cfquery` tag a result argument, and checking if that result has an insert ID:

Edit: used a function that wouldn't crash the `<cfif>`.

```
<cfquery name="qryTemp" datasource="someDSN" result="local.results">
if not exists (select someID from tempTable where someID = 20)
insert into tempTable (someID, colA, colB) values (1,2,3)
else
update tempTable set
colA = 2, colB =3
where someID = 1
</query>

<cfif structKeyExists(local.results, 'GENERATEDKEY')>
Do your stuff here...
</cfif>
```

(Check the [Documentation](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-tags/tags-p-q/cfquery.html) to see which `GENERATEDKEY` is best for your purpose)

Comment: Perfect, this will work with a small change. GeneratedKey will not be the part of result struct if it is an update. So I will need to add a validation check for its existence.

Comment: @CFML_Developer hah, yes... `isNumeric()` would be a bad call there. I replaced it with `structKeyExists()`.

Comment: @CFML_Developer - You could also just use [MERGE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/merge-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) with `OUTPUT inserted.id, $action AS Action;` The "action" indicates if it was an "insert" or "update". Though out of the box, concurrency is still an issue with both methods http://michaeljswart.com/2011/09/mythbusting-concurrent-updateinsert-solutions/

Answer (score 1):

Just to present another option, SQL 2008+ also supports [MERGE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/merge-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) for "upserts". Adding an OUTPUT clause will provide access to the special `$action` variable. As the name implies, it will indicate the action actually performed ("insert" or "update").

```
<cfquery name="qryTemp" datasource="#someDSN#">
    MERGE INTO tempTable tmp
    USING ( VALUES ( 1, 2, 3 )) 
        AS data (someID, colA, colB) 
        ON data.someID = tmp.someID
    WHEN MATCHED THEN
        UPDATE SET tmp.ColA = data.ColA
            , tmp.ColB = data.ColB
    WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
        INSERT (someID, colA, colB)
        VALUES (data.someID, data.colA, data.colB)
    OUTPUT inserted.someID AS ModifiedID
            , $action AS Action;
</cfquery>

<!--- Demo: Was an insert or update peformed? --->
<cfif qryTemp.Action eq "INSERT">
    ID inserted = <cfoutput>#qryTemp.ModifiedID#</cfoutput>
<cfelse>
    ID updated = <cfoutput>#qryTemp.ModifiedID#</cfoutput>
</cfif>
```

NB: Though out of the box, [concurrency is still an issue](http://michaeljswart.com/2011/09/mythbusting-concurrent-updateinsert-solutions/) with either methods.